# My APK does not re-install

Tags: android

I make my own APK and I installed it on phone. Then I change something, and I raise the versionCode from 10 to 11. But when I want to re-isntall the massage said that: "Application was not installed".

Before everything was working. When I check APK by aapt dump I see updated version in Manifest. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to uninstall your app first. Then you are able to install new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
adb install apk_file.apk
```

or you can use -d and -r with adb

```
adb install -r -d your_apk.apk
```

Comment: on the phone? I want install it just by clicking on it

Comment: you just uninstall it first through cmd line and then install it by clicking it'll work.

Comment: I cannot uninstall because it is for client. It worked before and I dont know why now not

Comment: Then you have to use the second cmd, it's the only option left without uninstalling. Do you have access to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

"App not installed" shows when an app with same package already installed in same device. just completely delete the first apk from your device.

Go to the Settings --> Apps --> Click on your App. ---> from menu select " Uninstall for All users ". Your app will be completely uninstalled and now you can try installing the new version with no issue.

Hope this will help you